# c++ - structure in map allocation

Tags: c++

As I known, map value is initialized by NULL(0). However, Below code is works well without any allocation. How is this code work?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct stuc{
    map<string, stuc> mp;
    int cnt;
}root;

int main() {
    stuc* u = &root;
    stuc* v = &(u->mp["test"]); // how to allocate?
    cout << v->cnt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without any allocation"? `std::map` handles dynamic allocations internally

Comment: If this part is confusing: `stuc* u = &root;` the `root` variable is a global variable.

Comment: OT but good reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: _"...map value is initialized by NULL(0)"_: this does not make any sense.

Comment: It is compiled well. https://ideone.com/8KHLAx

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you. that's what i want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you access a map with the `[]` operator like in

```
&(u->mp["test"])
```

there is a new key value pair allocated, default initialized, and inserted into the map if the element does not already exists [1]. In your program that is exactly what happens. The map does not already have an key `"test"`. Thus a new value is default constructed. Because you did not define a custom default constructor for your `stuc` struct, all its members are default initialized (`mp = {}` and `cnt = 0`). This is the reason why you get `0` if you read the `cnt` member of the newly created value.

[1] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Answer (score 1):

When accessing a key from your `std::map` which does not yet exist, it is inserted.

So by accessing `mp["test"]` a default constructed instance of `struct stuc` gets inserted for key "test"

Consider the following example where also a value is implicitly inserted when accessing a non-existing key and its value being set by your default constructor

```
 struct stuc{
    stuc(): cnt(42) { }
    stuc(int c): cnt(c) { }
    int cnt;
};

int main() {
    map<string, struct stuc> m;

    struct stuc s1(1);

    m["first"] = s1;
    cout << m["first"].cnt << endl;
    cout << "elements: " << m.size() << endl;
    cout << m["second"].cnt << endl;
    cout << "elements: " << m.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which will output:

```
1
elements: 1
42
elements: 2
```